# How to make visual studio 2008 ASP.NET designer faster?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, performance, designer

Visual studio designer for asp.net applications is generally very slow and i would like to know if there are any tips or guidelines for settings in order to get better.

The problem is usually noticed when i try to make a change in design or source view, especially in source view it may get non-responding for a couple of seconds.

Comment: Feel lucky that design mode works for you. At my last job, everytime you would try to open up the designer, Visual Studio would crash.

Comment: Either you should have reinstalled visual studio or fixed your broken project that was making it crash.

Comment: Haven't noticed it being slow, and I have a very slow computer (Early Opteron, 1GB RAM, Windows Vista).

Comment: TheTXI: no amount of brokenness of the project should cause V.S. to crash, unless V.S. is (also) broken.

Comment: Actually, thinking about it, i think it had to do with SiteCore.  I think VS choked when trying to render the sitecore stuff

Comment: @Ali unfortunately it does, at least it did back on vs 2003 - ran into trouble with custom controls that when changed you couldn't go into design view or it would crash / had to compile/close/open the solution for it - awful :( ... haven't had something like that - edge cases

Comment: Design view is officially banned from my VS IDE.

Comment: even if it works its slow, and i got a good machine. (4gb ram, quad, gf gts 8800..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced a very similar issue when I first installed Visual Studio Team System 2008 Development Edition.  I have issues with VS design view and could not switch to "Split View"

Reference the following ASP.NET thread [link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1191630.aspx) to see if any of this information helps..(Warning: It is quite long).

Answer (score 1):

Do you notice any difference when starting in Safe Mode?

```
devenv.exe /SafeMode
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have already installed the hotfix for VS2008 ASP.Net Designer performance issues? [Link](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/02/08/vs-2008-web-development-hot-fix-roll-up-available.aspx)